# How to read xlink:label value using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xlink

i need to get the xlink:label value(ASSET_1) from XML.

```
<MESSAGE xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<ABOUT_VERSIONS>
<ABOUT_VERSION SequenceNumber="1"  xlink:label="ASSET_1" >
<CreatedDatetime>2015-08-24T09:30:47Z</CreatedDatetime>
<DataVersionName>Purchase Example</DataVersionName>
</ABOUT_VERSION>
</ABOUT_VERSIONS>
</MESSAGE>
```

The Java Code i am trying is like below

```
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();            
XPath xPath = xpf.newXPath();

XPathExpression pathExpression = xPath.compile("MESSAGE/ABOUT_VERSIONS/ABOUT_VERSION");   
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("C:/Sample.xml");  
NodeList Nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("MESSAGE/ABOUT_VERSIONS/ABOUT_VERSION", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.println("SequenceNumber:: "+xPath.evaluate("MESSAGE/ABOUT_VERSIONS/ABOUT_VERSION/@SequenceNumber", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE));
System.out.println(" "+xPath.evaluate("MESSAGE/ABOUT_VERSIONS/ABOUT_VERSION/@xlink:label", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE));
```

```
OutPut
SequenceNumber:: SequenceNumber="1"

null
```

What is the mistake i am doing to pull the value of xlink:label ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@*[name()='xlink:label']` in place of `@xlink:label`. 
Also switching to `@*[local-name()='label']` should do the trick.

Comment: No , its still giving me null .

Comment: All calls to ```System.out.println(" "+xPath.evaluate("MESSAGE/ABOUT_VERSIONS/ABOUT_VERSION/@xlink:label", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE));```, ```System.out.println(" "+xPath.evaluate("MESSAGE/ABOUT_VERSIONS/ABOUT_VERSION/@*[name()='xlink:label']", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE));``` and ```System.out.println(" "+xPath.evaluate("MESSAGE/ABOUT_VERSIONS/ABOUT_VERSION/@*[local-name()='label']", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE));``` give you nulls?

Comment: Yes , All are returning null . I doubt do we need to register namespace for using the xlink . I am not sure . Just a thought.

Comment: That might help, but I'm not sure why none of previously mentioned ways do work. I checked it on Oracle Java 1.8.0_181.

Comment: My Bad , I just deleted the XML and recreted and tried with your code . Boom . It started working . Thanks.